# Prevent page jump on Router.Navigate

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

On click of the following link the current page jumps to the top before navigating to the other page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="goToTicket(x.refNo, $event)">{{x.ticketTitle}}</a>
```

**component.ts**

```
  goToTicket(refNo, e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['/ticket/ticket-details'], { queryParams: { id: refNo } });
  }
```

How do I prevent the page jump here?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove this code

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

or use

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ticket/ticket-details']" [queryParams]="{ id: x.refNo }">{{x.ticketTitle}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but does that mean I cannot prevent the page jump when using the click event on href?

Comment: You can by using event.preventDefault like you do right now. Your code is not working with your expected ?

Comment: Nope. it does not

Comment: Then I think you should use my approach or you can change to a div and add click event to that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrollPositionRestoration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881904/5621827)

you just need to disable this in the router configuration like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled'})
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-no-restore-ue9gxg)