# Angular keep scroll position when using the router

Tags: angular, scroll, routes

I am using a master-detail view where I navigate to the detail (child route) on selection in the master list. I'm trying to keep my scrolling position in the master list when I navigate back from the detail view to the master list.

I have tried using

```
RouterModule.forRoot([{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}], {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'}),
```

in my app routing module without success.

I was thinking that this was not working because the scrolling behaviour might get triggered before my list content is loaded succesfully so I tried another approach. In my list component, where my content gets initialized, I added this logic:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof Scroll),
    ).subscribe(event => {
        const scrollEvent = event as Scroll;
        of(scrollEvent).pipe(delay(1)).subscribe(scroll => {
            if (scroll.position) {
                this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(scroll.position);
            } else {
                this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
            }
        })
    })
```

Now this works when I navigate to my detail view and hit the back button. However this does **not** work when I use my built in back navigation in the detail component using the router as the scroll.position will always be null:

```
this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881698/angular-6-keep-scroll-position-when-the-route-changes ?